# Sending large zip files to Django/Tastypie server

Tags: python, django, sockets, tastypie

I want to send some zip files from a raspberry Pi to my windows server. The zips are about 2GB each.

I'm using python sockets to send them.

```
def sendFile():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print('Socket created')
    s.connect(("http://192.168.0.21:8000/api/v1/ziptest/", 8000))
    print("Connected")
    for x in range(len(zipTypes)):
        filename = '/logs/rel_5_0608.3800_val2/{}.zip'.format(zipTypes[x])
        print("filename {} ".format(filename))
        with open(filename,'rb') as infile:
            d = infile.read(1024)
            while d:
                s.send(d)
                d = infile.read(1024)
    infile.close()
```

I've then got my resource function:

```
class ResponseZipTest(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        limit = 100000
        queryset = TestZipModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = "ziptest"
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True

    # Hydration function
    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        print("Server is ready to receive")

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        return bundle
```

When I run `sendTest()` I get  `Name or service not known` but I can use `curl` on that URL just fine. My resource function never gets triggered.

My url file:

```
v1_api = Api(api_name='v1')
v1_api.register(ResponseZipTest())

test_model = ResponseZipTest()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
    url(r'^api/', include(v1_api.urls)),
    url(r'^api/', include(test_model.urls))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Are sockets the best way to send these files? Is there another method that'll simplify this?

Comment: Sockets operate on a low level (layer 5 - session, of the OSI network model I believe), whereas Django operates on the application layer (layer 7). If using raw sockets, you would need to actually send proper HTTP requests. You cannot use a `socket` to connect to a specifc protocol (HTTP) and route (`/api/v1/ziptest/`). Look into the `requests` module, or async alternatives.

Comment: @PatrykBratkowski You're correct. I've managed to get it working with requests. At the moment, I'm getting 415 error, but the file is being sent to the server which is strange. If the server doesn't need to send anything back to the client, requests seems to be the way to go.

Comment: You might need to explicitly set the content-type header: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file